# Angular 9 :core.js:6228 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm devopping a Dapp. I'm using Angular 9 for the frontend.
I get this error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

My code is

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Donation from '../../Donation.json';
import { TypeDon } from './interfaces/TypeDon.js';
'use strict';
var Web3 = require('web3');
var DonationABI = Donation.abi;

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:22000'));
const donationContract =  new web3.eth.Contract(DonationABI, '0xd0a5685a4ba479D0FF4E86Ca8300738573816c63');
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllTypes();
  }
  title = 'donationApp';

typeDons : TypeDon[]=[];
 getAllTypes(){
  donationContract.handleRevert=true; 
  donationContract.methods.getAllTypeDon().call(function(error, result){
    console.log("resultat :" + result);
    if(!error){      
      if(result!=null) {
           this.typeDons=result;
         }
        } 
      } else if(error)
        { console.log("error :" + error);}
      });
    }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Liste des donations :{{typeDons.length}}
  </h1>
</div>
  <table>
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Description</th>
           <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>

        <tr ngFor="let item of typeDons">
           <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
           <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
           <td>
              <button type="button" >Edit</button>
              <button type="button" >Delete</button>
           </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule, 
    HttpClientModule,

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I console.log the content of the table result and it contains data.
I think that the error comes from the html.
Any ideas to fix the problem

Answer (score 7):

1. The meaning of `this` keyword in a callback defined using `function` keyword denotes the scope of the function. Use arrow function to use class member variables.

```js
getAllTypes() {
  donationContract.handleRevert = true;
  donationContract.methods.getAllTypeDon().call((error, result) => {      // <-- use arrow function here
    console.log("resultat :" + result);
    if(!error) {
      if(result!=null) {
        this.typeDons=result;
      }
    } else { 
      console.log("error :" + error);
    }
  });
}
```

2. Use safe navigation operator [`?.`](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) in the template to check if the object is defined before trying to access it's properties.

```html
<tr ngFor="let item of typeDons">
  <td>{{ item?.name }}</td>               <!-- notice the question mark -->
  <td>{{ item?.description }}</td>
  <td>
    <button type="button" >Edit</button>
    <button type="button" >Delete</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I tried the code but,unfortunately, it cannot fix the problem

Comment: Do you still get the same error or a different error?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the html fixes the problem for me.